# Error handling in Scala with Futures

Tags: scala, error-handling, future

The following method uses a `future` to send email and then catches any exception `mail.send` might throw:

```
sendEmail(from: String, recipients: Seq[String],
  subject: String, body: (Option[Txt], Option[Html])) = Try {

  import com.typesafe.plugin._
  import scala.concurrent.future
  import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext

  val mail = use[MailerPlugin].email

  mail.addFrom(from)
  recipients.map(mail.addRecipient(_))
  subject.map(mail.setSubject(subject)

  future {
    try {
      mail.send(body._1.map(_.body).getOrElse(""), body._2.map(_.body).getOrElse(""))
    } catch {
      case NonFatal(e) => Logger.warn("[%s] error sending email".format(ClassName, subject), e)
    }
  }
}
```

The method above returns either `Success`or `Failure` – for example `mail.addFrom` might throw an exception if the sender email is invalid. Having said that, is it correct the way I deal with possible exceptions thrown inside the `future` block?

Comment: The `future` method itself does this already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `try` in `future`.

```
val f = future {
  mail.send(body._1.map(_.body).getOrElse(""), body._2.map(_.body).getOrElse(""))
}

f.onFailure{
  case NonFatal(e) => Logger.warn("[%s] error sending email".format(ClassName, subject), e)
}
```

`Future` could contain successful result or failure in [`Try`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.Try) container. You could get `Try` in `onComplete` method, or transform [`Failure`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.Failure) to [`Success`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.Success) using `recover` method.